# Accept ICMP packets (ping) with specific length - Iptable rules

Tags: iptables, icmp, packet

I am going to filter Ping request to my server, and only accepts ping request with length 920.

```
ping -l 920 serrveraddress
```

I am using the following two command in iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m length --length 1:920 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

But it accept all the ping requests. Could you please guide me through this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--length 1:920` means any packet with size 1 to 920 bytes. Default ping packet is much smaller than 920 bytes.